# Create a dll for Lua with C: undefined reference to 'luaL_register'

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to compile this C code to obtaina dll:

```
#include<windows.h>

#include<lauxlib.h>
#include<lua.h>

/*************/
/* FUNCTIONS */
/*************/

/* helloluatex_greetings */
static int helloluatex_greetings(lua_State *L)
{
       printf("Hello to LuaTeX from the world's smallest DLL!");
       return 0;
}

/***************************/
/* Lua name to C functions */
/***************************/
static const luaL_Reg helloluatex[] = {{"greetings", helloluatex_greetings},
                                         {NULL, NULL}};

/****************************/
/* MAIN DLL EXPORT FUNCTION */
/****************************/
LUA_API luaopen_helloluatex (lua_State *L)
{
        luaL_register(L, "helloluatex", helloluatex);
        return 1;
}
```

But I receive this error:

```
[linker error] undefined reference to 'luaL_register'
```

I'm using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 on Windows Vista.

Do you see whereI fail?

Comment: You have to link a library called `lua51.lib` (or something like that, it's been a while)

Comment: you can do it in the compiler options for your project under Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input and list `lua51.lib`, or put `#pragma comment(lib, "lua51.lib")` in your code somewhere.

Comment: @ Seth Carneige: if you put it as an answer, I'll accept it!!! Many thanks man!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link `lua51.lib` into your project, which contains the definitions for the `lua_*` functions. You can do this by going to  Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input and adding `lua51.lib` to the list of libraries, or by adding

```
#pragma comment(lib, "lua51.lib")
```

Somewhere in your code.